# Struggling to find loop invariant in power function

Tags: correctness-proof, loop-invariants

I am struggling to find a good loop invariant for the following function, which returns a^b where a is a real number and b is a natural number:

```
power <- function(a, b){
     c <- 1
     while(b > 0){
          if(b %% 2 == 1){
               c <- c * a
          }
          b <- floor(b / 2)
          a <- a * a
     }
     return c
}
```

I've ran through the loop with a couple of examples, and I see that it has 2 kinds of cases; when b is even or odd. I also understand that on the kth iteration, a = a_0^(2^k), but I am struggling to find a proper invariant as there is no real iterating variable to use.

Comment: Sorry, that was two typos. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may clarify things to use different variable names. Let's call $x$ the desired result of $a^b$ where $a$ and $b$ are the inputs. With variables $c', a', b'$ initialized to $c' = 1, a'=a, b'=b$, you are basically maintaining that $x = c'(a')^{b'}$. At the end you have $x = c'$ because $b' = 0$. Each step "transfers" half of the exponent to the base of the exponentiation, or in the odd case, the coefficient.